# instanceof operator with a nested class

Tags: java, nested-class, instanceof

Here I have a little curiosity:

```
if (!(Outer instanceof Outer.Nested))
{
    System.out.println("IT IS NOT THE SAME!!");
}
```

Why does the compiler not understand that `Outer.Nested` does not extend `Outer` and cannot be an instance of it, and therefore give back a compilation error?

Note that if it was the other way round: `Outer.Nested instanceof Outer` it would not work.

Comment: Are `Outer` and `Outer.Nested` two classes?

Comment: Please show the `Outer` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this statement could not compile, if `Outer` is a class type:

```
if (!(Outer instanceof Outer.Nested))  // Outer is not an expression: Expression expected
```

Without no precised context in the question, I imagine you would deal with a scenario like this:

```
public class Outer {

        private class Inner {
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test t = new Test();
            Inner i = t.new Inner();
            System.out.println(i instanceof Test);  //inconvertible types => normal
            System.out.println(t instanceof Inner); // inconvertible types => normal
        }

    }
```

All happens normally thus.

If your scenario is similar: sounds like an issue with your compiler process.

If your scenario isn't similar: please update your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

From [JLS 15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

```
RelationalExpression:
    ....
    RelationalExpression instanceof ReferenceType
```

> The type of the RelationalExpression operand of the instanceof operator must be a reference type or the null type; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

In other words, the left hand side of instanceof must be a reference to some object or `null`. `Outer` looks like a class name, which is neither of those things.

You may be looking for [Class.isAssignableFrom()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29), which tells you whether one class is a superclass of another.